# What the difference/similarity between shell programming and unix programming?

Tags: shell, unix

Difference or similarities between shell programming and unix programming.

Comment: What is the difference between doing your own homework and asking Stack Overflow to do it for you?

Comment: @subrat : It's similar to the difference between "You have to cook Lasagne according to a recipe in an Italian cookbook", and "You have to cook something which people in Sicily are willing to eat".

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is shell scripting instead of shell programing. The scripting is the right terminology.
"Shell scripting" is the term which is a collection of command to do a specific task.

"Unix programming" refers to programming explicitly for a unix environment. This would include programming for shells that conform to a relevant standard